# Django queryset: Exclude list of emails using endswith

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm running metrics on user data and want exclude users that have bogus emails like '@example.com' or '@test.com'.

I tried

```
emails_to_exclude = ['@example.com', '@test.com', '@mailinator.com' ....]
Users.objects.exclude(email__endswith__in=emails_to_exclude)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Looks like `endswith` and `in` don't play nice with each other. Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Simply loop over the QuerySet, as [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

```
emails_to_exclude = ['@example.com', '@test.com', '@mailinator.com' ....]
users = Users.objects
for exclude_email in emails_to_exclude:
    users = users.exclude(email__endswith=exclude_email)
users = users.all()
```

Comment: Simple, correct and easy to understand.  Building up querysets like this is a great technique for building complex search tools.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this with regular expressions in single query.

```
emails_to_exclude = ['@example.com', '@test.com', '@mailinator.com' ....]
User.objects.exclude(email__regex = "|".join(emails_to_exclude))
```

I don't know the efficiency of this query.

This will not work for [SQLite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex), as it has no built in regular expression support.

Answer (score 2):

One more way to achieve this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q

emails_to_exclude = ['@example.com', '@test.com', '@mailinator.com']

users = User.objects.all()

filters = Q()
for ending in emails_to_exclude:
    filters |= Q(email__endswith=ending)

filtered_users = users.filter(~filters)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably loop over the emails and build up a [Q Object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). Actually, you can probably do a 1-liner if you're clever.

```
User.objects.exclude(bitwise_or_function[Q(email__endswith=e) for e in emails_to_exclude])
```

Something like that. I don't remember the function to bitwise-OR a whole list together, my Python's rusty.

Answer (score 1):

This should works with the latest version of Python and Django. The `reduce` function is a good friend.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q

emails_to_exclude = ['@example.com', '@test.com', '@mailinator.com' ....]
users = ( Users.objects
    .exclude( reduce( or_, ( 
        Q(( "email__endswith", k ))
        for k in emails_to_exclude 
    ) ) )
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I changed the exclusion input to make it a `set` and to not have the "@".  Otherwise, this should do what you want.

```
>>> emails = ['foo@example.com', 'spam@stackoverflow.com', 'bad@test.com']
>>> excludes = {'example.com', 'test.com', 'mailinator.com'}
>>> [email for email in emails if email.split('@')[-1] not in excludes]
['spam@stackoverflow.com']
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You're executing a potentially very large query then iterating over that entire queryset. Ideally, you want to make a query that only contains the exact data you need.